# Add to text in url based on a vector of character strings in r

Tags: r, string, url, paste

Suppose you have a vector of character strings such as a series of locations like below...

```
cities<-c("San Diego County","Fresno County", "Los Angeles County", 
             "Lake County")
```

...and additionally you have some url such as `www.fakewebsite.com/search_loc=`. What would the appropriate syntax be to paste each value from the "cities" vector to the end of the url (following `search_loc=`) such that all spaces between strings are separated with the following `$50` and for each url to end with the following `%100`. Ideally, I would like the result to look like the following:

```
cities               url
San Diego County     www.fakewebsite.com/search_loc=San$50Diego$50County%100
Fresno County        www.fakewebsite.com/search_loc=Fresno$50County%100
Los Angeles County   www.fakewebsite.com/search_loc=Los$50Angeles$50County%100
Lake County          www.fakewebsite.com/search_loc=Lake$50County%100
```

Note: The `cities` vector has a maximum of three separate strings (i.e. two white spaces) and a minimum of two separate strings (i.e. one white space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `paste0` and `gsub`, we can replace empty spaces with "$50" and end it with "%100"

```
paste0(base_url, gsub("\\s+", "$50", cities), "%100")

#[1] "www.fakewebsite.com/search_loc=San$50Diego$50County%100"  
#[2] "www.fakewebsite.com/search_loc=Fresno$50County%100"       
#[3] "www.fakewebsite.com/search_loc=Los$50Angeles$50County%100"
#[4] "www.fakewebsite.com/search_loc=Lake$50County%100"
```

**data**

```
cities<-c("San Diego County","Fresno County", "Los Angeles County", 
      "Lake County")
base_url <- "www.fakewebsite.com/search_loc="
```